# Webstorm/File Watcher - how to compile and minify coffeescript at a same time?

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

How to automatically minify javascript output files after compiling coffeescript files in webstorm?

Update: 
I was going to use UglifyJS or YUI Compressor with File Watcher but it will "watch" for changes on all JS files. That's why I don't want to use the File Watcher. Is there another way to solve this problem? (keyboard shortcut to minify the files that I am editing only?)

Comment: Welcome to so! -) If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [webstorm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html):

> WebStorm supports integration with the following JavaScript
>   minification tools:
>
> - [YUI Compressor](https://npmjs.org/package/yui)
> - [UglifyJS](https://npmjs.org/package/uglify-js)
> - [Closure Compiler](https://npmjs.org/package/closure)
>
> In WebStorm, minifier configurations are called **File Watchers**. For
>   each supported minifier, WebStorm provides a predefined File Watcher
>   template. Predefined File Watcher templates are available at the
>   WebStorm level. To run a minifier against your project files, you need
>   to create a project-specific File Watcher based on the relevant
>   template, at least, specify the path to the minifier to use on your
>   machine.
>
> - [Installing and configuring the Closure Compiler minification tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html#d63386e1096)
> - [Installing and configuring the YUI Compressor JS or UglifyJS minification tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html#d63386e1133)
> - [Creating a File Watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html#d63386e1259)
> - [Minifying the code](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/minifying-javascript.html#d63386e1355)

I assume you could create your own transpiler config for watching and autominifying only coffeescript files:

> - [Transpiling CoffeeScript to JavaScript](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/transpiling-coffeescript-to-javascript.html)
> - [Examples of customizing the behaviour of a transpiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/transpiling-coffeescript-to-javascript.html#d72638e468)

Comment: I need a way to minify only javascript files which are compiled from coffeescript not all (My project are using both javascript and coffeescript). Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a new or edit the predefined coffeescript transpiler? I don't know the command to minify the output. I've tried 'coffee -h' but did not see any option to minify/compress the output file. Could you please guide me more?

Comment: CoffeeScript compiler doesn't have options for producing minified output. So you have to use 2 tools here: coffeescript transpiler to produce .js and one of minification tools mentioned above to compress the output. And 2 file watchers: one will listen to changes in .cofee files and run the transpiler. another -  listent to changes in .js files and compress them

Comment: Thanks, [tag:lena]. I got it. So there is no way to listen changes only on the output of CoffeeScript. I wish Webstorm can support to condition File Watcher by using regular expression somehow.